# Change view onLongPressGesture

Tags: swiftui

```
 var body: some View {
    let zstack = ZStack {
      // Zstack contents


    }
    .onLongPressGesture {
      nextView()
      }
    }
```

I've got a SwiftUI view where I want to pop a new view when I perform a long press on it. How do I go to nextView? I seem to only be able to change views by using navigationLinks but in this case I don't have a button to be pressed.

Comment: It is not clear how and where do you want to present `nextView`: in ZStack, instead of ZStack, over ZStack, with or w/o transition/animation and which one, etc. - the solutions might differ heavily.

Comment: I said "pop a new view", so on top of this entire View, not just the ZStack.

Answer (score 0):

By using below code we can achieve 
Here for example purpose taken Button

struct ContentView: View {

```
@GestureState var isLongPressed = false

  var body: some View {
    let longPress = LongPressGesture()
        .updating($isLongPressed) { value, state, transaction in
            state = value
        }
    return Button(/*...*/)
        .gesture(longPress)
}
```

}